# Universal Analytics Event Tracking on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I've done a lot of research on this topic, but now I've hit a major roadblock:

On my Wordpress website, I want to track the main navigation link "Dreamer" under "3D Printer". I am using Universal Analytics.

Currently, I use a CSS-PHP-JS plugin to fire the following Javascript code that supposedly tracks the event, but it is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   ;(function ($) {
      $("a#menu-item-4893").each(function () {
         var href = $(this).attr("href");
         var target = $(this).attr("target");
         var text = $(this).text();

         // When someone clicks these links:
         $(this).click(function (event) { 
            event.preventDefault(); // Don't open the link yet

            // Create a custom event"
            ga('send', 'event', 'Internal Link', 'click-dreamer-nav', 'flashforge-usa.com/dreamer-3d-printer', 42);

            // Now wait 300 milliseconds...
            setTimeout(function () {
               // ... and open the link as usual:
               window.open(href, (!target ? "_self" : target));
            }, 300);
         });
      });
   })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I actually have two other variations of codes that you can find in the footer section of the website:

- Variation 2: Track the Creator Pro link under Dreamer.
- Variation 3: Track a click on [downloads](http://www.flashforge-usa.com/support/).

So far none are throwing errors in the Chrome console, but my UA isn't recording the events.

Can someone please offer some guidance?

Comment: Every one of this links will result in a new pageview, why can't you check how many times the page was viewed?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by trying something like this, which would track clicks on menu elements with links to "http://www.flashforge-usa.com/dreamer-3d-printer/".

If that allows you to track clicks Events for the menu item, you might then look at setting up tracking for your other links.

```
;(function ($) {
   $('.mpcth_nav').on('click', 'a[href="http://www.flashforge-usa.com/dreamer-3d-printer/"]', function (event) {
      // Temporarily prevent the default browser behavior for clicks:
      event.preventDefault();

      // Keep a reference to the Element's attributes:
      var link = $(this);
      var linkDestination = link.attr('href');
      var linkTarget = link.attr('target');

      // Create a custom event:
      ga('send', {
         'hitType': 'event',
         'eventCategory': 'Internal Link', // The Object that was interacted with (Required).
         'eventAction': 'click-dreamer-nav', // The type of interaction (Required).
         'eventLabel': 'flashforge-usa.com/dreamer-3d-printer', // Label for categorizing events (Optional).
         'eventValue': 42, // Event value (Optional).
         'hitCallback': function () { // Called when the Hit was sent (Optional).
            // Navigate to the link once Google Analytics was notified:
            window.open(linkDestination, (!linkTarget ? '_self' : linkTarget));
         }
      });
   });
})(jQuery);
```

For more details about Event tracking in Google Analytics, you can refer to the online documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events